# Solr FunctionQuery: gte, lte, eq functions

Tags: solr

Solr FunctionQuery has a DIV(x,y) function. I have such a need if y=0, then y should be equal to x.

In other words, I need to represent the following logic with FunctionQuery:

```
if y == 0, return 1 /* i.e. DIV(x,x) */
else, return DIV(x,y)
```

Somehow, from the Solr doc, I cannot find any comparison function, e.g. EQ(x, value), etc. for me to use.

Will anyone be able to give me a hint to construct my desired logic using FunctionQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: Doesnt a `==` work for you? something like `if(y==0,1,DIV(x,y))`?

Comment: It does not work. I am getting Expected ',' at position 17 in 'if(exposure_count==0,1,div(1,exposure_count))'. This is what I try to  use the boost function in the query. The full syntax is {!boost b=if(exposure_count==0,1,div(1,exposure_count))}

Comment: To add: If I remove the ==0, it worked. {!boost+b%3Dif(exposure_count,1,div(1,exposure_count))}. Seems like there is no way to do comparison.

Comment: actually you need to switch the arguments. exposure_count = 0 is interpreted as false. So your condition would be `{!boost+b%3Dif(exposure_count,div(1,exposure_count),1)}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clean up this question and log what is my final solution, thanks to Srikanth Venugopalan comment:

> actually you need to switch the arguments. exposure_count = 0 is interpreted as false. So your condition would be {!boost b=if(exposure_count,div(1,exposure_count),1)}"

As it seems, Lucid works [documentation](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Function+Queries) does have a mistake. The FunctionQuery parser does not take comparison operators such as ==, at least this is what I found by looking into the sourcecode. Also, the field separator for IF() function should be ,(comma) and not ;(semi-colon).

The official Solr [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#if) is correct.

Answer (score 2):

For string terms this works:

if(termfreq(fieldname,"value"),2,1)

which yields 2 if "value" is contained in "fieldname" (termfreq will be >0)

Answer (score 0):

you can use == for equals and if conditional statement as below :-

e.g.  `if(y == 0; 1; DIV(x,y))`

Check for the example @ [Documentation](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Function+Queries)

`if(color=="red"; 100; if(color=="green"; 50; 25))` :
This function checks the document field "color", and if it is "red" returns 100, if it is "green" returns 50, else returns 25.

Edit :-

Solr [if](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#if) wiki mentions , (comma) as seperator

e.g. `if(exists(myField),100,0)`

Comment: I am getting Expected ',' at position 17 in 'if(exposure_count==0,1,div(1,exposure_count))'. This is what I try to  use the boost function in the query. The full syntax is {!boost b=if(exposure_count==0,1,div(1,exposure_count))}

Comment: the seperator is ; (semi colon) and not , (comma)

Comment: To add: If I remove the ==0, it worked. {!boost+b%3Dif(exposure_count,1,div(1,exposure_count))}. Seems like there is no way to do comparison.

Comment: try changing the seperator and try to compare as int 0 or string "0", it should work.

Comment: ;(semi colon) is not correct. Should be comma. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#if.

Comment: No good. still getting Expected ',' at position 17 in 'if(exposure_count=="0";1;div(1,expos
ure_count))' when using ;(semi colon). But this one works for me {!boost b=if(exposure_count,1,div(1,exposure_count))}

Comment: Documentation seems to be different on Official docs and the Lucid works. Am not sure only using exposure_count in the if statement is it checking for the field if it exists or not.